# Remove Duplicate Records in Mysql Only

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows

I have a following table

```
------------
id name
------------
1  master
2  datagrid 
3  zewa
4  leumas
5  delta
6  master
7  master
8  master
9  delta
```

I just want to remove duplicate (repeating) rows. So from the above table, all the rows for "master" and "delta" should be removed.

**Note:** I don't want to use temporary table or any Alter statement. I just want to use a Delete query

Comment: **all** the rows for "master" and "delta" should be removed? Not just all except one?

Comment: No, not even a single record should exist. All repeating rows should be removed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC MySQL does not allow you to reference the mutating table in an `IN` clause except by adding an additional layer of indirection.

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE  name IN (SELECT name
                FROM   (SELECT name
                        FROM   YourTable
                        GROUP  BY name
                        HAVING COUNT(name) > 1) AS T)
```

Answer (score -2):

DELETE from table where name in (select name from table group by name having count(name)>1);

Comment: This wont work ... you cannot use a reference to the mutating table in the subquery ....